While Loop Function - Removing Duplicates
How do I resolve the duplications on the while loop function. I want it to update to a certain key.
Declare @loop1 int = 0     
Declare @loop2 int = (Select count(*) from #WorkCentre2)    
Declare @SQL varchar(8000)    
    
while @loop1  < @loop2    
begin    
 Set @loop1 = @loop1 + 1     
 Set @SQL = 'Alter table #temp1 add [' + (Select WorkCentre from #WorkCentre2  where AutoID = @loop1) + '] varchar(50)'    
 exec(@SQL)    
     
 Set @SQL = '    
 Update #temp1 set     
  [' + (Select WorkCentre from #WorkCentre2  where AutoID = @loop1) + '] = ManufacturingTracking.PercentCompleted    
 From ManufacturingTracking (nolock)    
      inner join #temp1    
   on #temp1.ID = ManufacturingTracking.ManufacturingTrackingId    
   and ManufacturingTracking.WorkCentre = ''' + (Select WorkCentre from #WorkCentre2  where AutoID = @loop1) + ''''    
exec(@SQL)

Results:



ID
SalesOrder
Job
Customer
MaterialType
PartThickness
QtyRequired
LCT - LASER CUTTING
BNS - BENDING SIMPLE
QCT - QUALITY CONTROL




139690
000001000071138
JG00415389
GHH002 - GHHMM MANUFACTURING   (PTY)  LTD
SS304L
6.000000
3.000000
100.00
NULL
NULL


139691
000001000071138
JG00415389
GHH002 - GHHMM MANUFACTURING   (PTY)  LTD
SS304L
6.000000
3.000000
NULL
100.00
NULL


139692
000001000071138
JG00415389
GHH002 - GHHMM MANUFACTURING   (PTY)  LTD
SS304L
6.000000
3.000000
NULL
NULL
0.00




What is this, T-SQL? Please add relevant language tag(s), and a more elaborate explanation of the problem you're having - you might want to review the How to Ask a Good Question page

Aside: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use QuoteName() to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. New Table with a space or reserved words like From. It does more than toss in a pair of square brackets around any string.

What's the question exactly? What isn't working?

Aside: As a rule, the count(*) of rows with an identity column does not mean that rows exist with identity for all values from 1 to max( identityCol ) = count(*). The start value and increment may not be 1 (or may have been changed), rows may have been deleted, values may have been explicitly inserted using set identity_insert, ... . If a loop is required then a cursor may be appropriate.

Set loop1 = loop1 + 1 - should be done at the end.

Lets take a step back. It appears that you are attempting to manually construct a pivot of the ManufacturingTracking data joined with the #temp (orders?) table.
If you just intend to SELECT * FROM #Temp in the end, you can skip  all of this this looping logic and construct the final result directly using a PIVOT.
SELECT *
FROM #Temp T
LEFT JOIN ManufacturingTracking MT
  ON MT.ManufacturingTrackingId = T.ID
PIVOT (
    SUM(MT.PercentCompleted)
    FOR MT.WorkCentre IN ([LCT - LASER CUTTING], [BNS - BENDING SIMPLE], [QCT - QUALITY CONTROL])
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.ID

Results:



ID
SalesOrder
Job
Customer
MaterialType
PartThickness
QtyRequired
ManufacturingTrackingId
LCT - LASER CUTTING
BNS - BENDING SIMPLE
QCT - QUALITY CONTROL




139690
000001000071138
JG00415389
GHH002 - GHHMM MANUFACTURING (PTY) LTD
SS304L
6.000000
3.000000
139690
100.000000
null
null


139691
000001000071138
JG00415389
GHH002 - GHHMM MANUFACTURING (PTY) LTD
SS304L
6.000000
3.000000
139691
null
100.000000
null


139692
000001000071138
JG00415389
GHH002 - GHHMM MANUFACTURING (PTY) LTD
SS304L
6.000000
3.000000
139692
null
null
0.000000



If the WorkCentre values are not fixed, you can use dynamic SQL to construct an appropriate data-driven column list.
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(W.WorkCentre), ', ')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY W.WorkCentre) -- You may need to define a different order
    FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT MT.WorkCentre
       FROM ManufacturingTracking MT
    ) W
)

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT *
    FROM #Temp T
    LEFT JOIN ManufacturingTracking MT
        ON MT.ManufacturingTrackingId = T.ID
    PIVOT (
        SUM(MT.PercentCompleted)
        FOR MT.WorkCentre IN (' + @Columns + ')
    ) PVT
    ORDER BY PVT.ID
'

PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)

The results are the same, except for the pivoted column order.
This db<>fiddle demonstrates both of the above.
